# Where is this dev/default copy coming from? 'The token "n-more-friends" will be replaced with a string like "4 more friends."'

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-stream-story

A page we've developed is generating some strange messages when multiple friends "like" it.  It's a page with two admins and an association with a clean, empty dummy app.

http://www.nike.com/plus/products/training/

When a single friend likes the page, it displays in the stream correctly as:

> [name] likes a link

When two friends like the page, it displays in the stream correctly as:

> [name] and Jon Doe like a link

...however when there are many friends and others liking the link, this is what appears:

> [name] and 3 other friends like a Story in Feed about liking an item. The token "n-more-friends" will be replaced with a string like "4 more friends."

I've uploaded a screencap here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz8sv.png

We can't figure out where this copy is coming from, or where it might be set.  The application cited in the metadata is new, empty, and has no actions or objects associated with it.

Any ideas?

I apologize ahead of time in case I'm just being a fool.

Comment: So its literally printing  `n more-friends" will be replaced with a string like "4 more friends.`  Is this a facebook page or a website?  If non facebook page how are users liking it, and how is the message being generated?

Comment: @Nix - It's a non-facebook page that has a facebook like button on it, a direct cut-and-paste from the code generator [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Same as every other like button I've placed on any number of pages, except that this time I've provided metadata for admins and an app_id.

Oddly enough, the email notification's copy is just fine - this morning I received this message: "David Seikichi Kamida, Quinlin McGregor, and 95 other people like Nike+ Training."